# Get Contents of Static Property from a Type Stored in a Variable

Tags: ios, swift, generics

The code below is quite contrived but the bottom line is I have a variable that contains a type (e.g. `let someType: AnyObject = SomeClass.self`) and I want to get the value of a static property belonging to the type stored in that variable. Is this possible in Swift?

```
class SomeClass {
    var someDict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = {
        "aKey": SomeOtherClass.self
        "anotherKey": SomeOtherOtherClass.self
    }

    func someFunction() {
        let someType: AnyObject? = someDict["aKey"]

        // This line is incorrect, but how would get the static value I am after?
        let aString: String = someType.someString
        println(aString)
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    static var someString: String = "Hello World"
}

class SomeOtherOtherClass {
    static var someString: String = "Foo Bar"
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to inherit all your 'OtherClass'es  from a base class?

Comment: @lukya In fact, I do.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to change `AnyObject` references to `SomeOtherBaseClass.Type` where SomeOtherBaseClass is a parent class of both `SomeOtherClass` and `SomeOtherOtherClass`.

```
class SomeClass {
    var someDict: Dictionary<String, SomeOtherBaseClass.Type> = {
        "aKey": SomeOtherClass.self
        "anotherKey": SomeOtherOtherClass.self
    }

    func someFunction() {
        let someType: SomeOtherBaseClass.Type? = someDict["aKey"]

        // This line is incorrect, but how would get the static value I am after?
        let aString: String = someType!.someString
        println(aString)
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass {
    static var someString: String = "Hello World"
}

class SomeOtherOtherClass {
    static var someString: String = "Foo Bar"
}
```

Thanks to @lukya for nudging me in the right direction.